# How to orbit with finer precision

Tags: 3d-view

When moving objects or vertices around you can hold Shift for finer precision. This doesn't seem to work with orbiting or panning the view however. Can I toggle slow down orbiting or panning without changing my mouse sensitivity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change Orbit Sensitivity in the Preferences(<kbd>F4</kbd> -> <kbd>p</kbd>):

[image]

You could also add two entries to your keymap to make a key that you could press and while it's pressed the sensitivity is set to some value, but when you release it, it resets it to some other:

[image]

Note that one is set to "Press", another to "Release".
The operator: `wm.context_set_value` sets the value for `preferences.inputs.view_rotate_sensitivity_turntable` here. You would have to play with the values to find the ones comfortable for you(mine are quite low, because I am using a pen tablet right now).

It doesn't work while you are orbiting, you have to press and hold the key before you start. It might be possible to make it work while you orbit, but that would require a more complex approach.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I forgot to mention I'm using Blender 2.79. It's basically the same settings, however changing the orbit or mouse sensitivity doesn't seem to have any effect. It works fine in 2.8 however.

Comment: The workaround to change the sensitivity with a hotkey is a pretty great idea though!

Comment: I cannot find any solution in 2.79, I am afraid.